# Install Ubuntu as non-superuser

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Please advise how I can install Ubuntu as a non-superuser. I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 onto my PC with Window 7 with dual boot. However, I see that the installation says that I am installing as a superuser after I selected Something Else as the Installation Type. I did not get the simple option to install Ubuntu Alongside Windows where I can select the partition size. Instead, I had the screen with multiple options/partitions.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the installer does not correctly detect other already installed systems, but this has nothing to do with the installation wizard running as superuser (root). This is necessary, because otherwise it could not access the disk with enough privileges to e.g. repartition, format or write to the boot sector. You should probably look for a guide on how to do the manual installation/partitioning.

Comment: [how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instruction (kept as easy as possible) on how to install Ubuntu properly ...

Boot from Ubuntu installation media and highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing**.
On the live desktop press the Windows key and type GParted into the search field.

Open **GParted** and reduce the Windows partition if there is no unallocated space.
Create **two new partitions** and format one with **ext4** - the other with **linux-swap**.

Now start the **Ubuntu installer** from the desktop and choose **Something else**.
Select the ext4 partition you have created before and choose `/` as mount point.

Select the same *disk* (e.g. `/dev/sda`) on which Windows is installed to install the bootloader 
(without a partition number) ... otherwise you won't be able to start into GRUB bootloader ...

*Note:* In case you have a computer with UEFI:
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.

Regarding the superuser topic ... read the comment from @ByteCommander :

> Sometimes the installer does not correctly detect other already installed systems, but this has nothing to do with the installation wizard running as superuser (root). This is necessary, because otherwise it could not access the disk with enough privileges to e.g. repartition, format or write to the boot sector. [...] - [ByteCommander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) ([link to comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698582/install-ubuntu-as-non-superuser/698590?noredirect=1#comment1023169_698582))

Comment: As you are a reputation 1 user: If this answer did help you, please do not forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text,
which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) ! **;-)**

Comment: Hey, you stole Fabby's canned comment... - But I would add a paragraph about the non-superuser thing the OP talks about. You may use my comment on the question if you want. Oh, and +1 :D

Comment: @ByteCommander : Thank you for your contribution ! ... but STEALIN' ? - Fabby ADVISED me to use that - HA ! ... and thanks for +1 my friend ! =)

Comment: That first sentence was meant to be read with a big **;-)**

Comment: I included the relevant parts of my comment into your answer... You don't mind that, do you? ;)